# How do i change the Layout page based on whether a user is logged in or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

The way i want a user to be determined to be logged in, is by putting his Username in session storage and then finding the `User` object that corresponds to that Username in the database.

this is how `Login` and `SignUp` look in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignUp(User _user)
    {
        _user.Authorize = CustomRoles.RegisteredUser;
        int lastuserid = entities.Users.Last().UserID;
        _user.UserID = lastuserid + 1;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(_user.UserName, CustomRoles.RegisteredUser);
            entities.Users.Add(_user);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(_user);
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        LoginViewModel LVM = new LoginViewModel();
        HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserName"];
        if (existingCookie != null)
        {
            LVM.UserName = existingCookie.Value;
        }
        Session["UserName"] = LVM.UserName;
        return View(LVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (u.RememberMe)
            {
                HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserName"];
                if (existingCookie != null)
                {

                    existingCookie.Value = u.UserName;
                    existingCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-20);
                }


                HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", u.UserName);
                newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
                Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
            }
            var v = entities.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

this is the actual `Login` page:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model Car_Dealership.Models.LoginViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div style="border:1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(u=>u.RememberMe)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=>u.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" />

            <a href="/Home/SignUp">Sign Up</a>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

and to change the layouts i put this in `_ViewStart`:

```
    @{
    if (Session["UserName"]!=null)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/UserLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }


}
```

What happens is that `Session["UserName"]` gets the username in the first `Login` actionmethod from `LVM` which gets it from an already existing cookie, then i think everything just does what i think it's supposed to do but i still don't get the different layout page. i think it gets screwed up in the LINQ thing where i try to get a `User` object into `v` but i'm not really sure.

Comment: you're trying to get the different layout page for the login view?  if so remove `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` from the top of the Login view

Comment: @JamieD77 no, i'm trying to change the layout page for the duration of the session for a user that's logged in. the different layout page also contains some links that an anonymous user has no access to and a registered user does

Comment: when you set the `UserName` session variable use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]` and see if it changes anything

Comment: You should also set that value after a successful login.. i dont see you doing that anywhere in the `[HttpPost] Login`

Comment: @Bearcat9425 I think i made Usernames unique in the database but i'm not sure, i should probably do something about that anyway. I don't think i understand what you mean by using If(v.Count>0).

Comment: Doing `Session["UserName"] = LVM.UserName;` in the login Get method doesn't seem correct to me.. you should only do that if the login is valid it seems

Comment: @JamieD77 changing it didn't seem to change anything, also removing `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` causes it to not display the page at all

Comment: @JamieD77 i put `Session["UserName"] = LVM.UserName;` before i redirect to `Index` in `if(v!=null)` because it doesn't make sense for it to be in the login method and that seemed like the best place to put it to me. i think